# Making a rectangular vector shapefile that is a perfect square in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, rectangle

I'm having trouble making a square vector shapefile, using "Make Rectangle from Extent" (or anything really).

I've googled for hours, regrettably the older plugins aren't compatible and of course I tried using SHIFT and mouse, but nothing.

Comment: A perfect square is not possible on the surface of the globe, at least, not by using a rectangle creation tool in decimal degrees.

Comment: At least the QRectangleCreator makes perfect rectangles for me. With perfect rectangle I mean the one that has vertices only at minx, maxx, miny, maxy locations.

Comment: Wow! A solution that works... in less than 12 hours...you guys are flipping wonderful. MrXsquared... awesome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds" from processing toolbox to create squares out of points:

[image]

As you can see on my example, this strongly depends on your CRS and/or location on the earth. Here only the point near the equator creates an almost-square in its appearance using on-the-fly Pseudo-Mercator Projection (EPSG:3857), but they all are perfect squares in degrees, as you can see when the "background" is in degrees as well (WGS84 - EPSG:4326):

[image]

So better use a projected CRS like UTM, depending on what you actually want and mean by "perfect square".

In this second example you can see the result using "Sphere Azimuthal Equidistant" projection (ESRI:53032) in red. They are perfect squares in meters and its appearance using the same projection as on-the-fly for background.

[image]

But they are not, if you use another on-the-fly projection for appearance like EPSG:3857 again:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a rectangle, then use the `node tool` [image] from the digitizing toolbar to mark single nodes, then change their coordinates in the appearing table so all sides are parallel, aka both top nodes have the same Y-value, both eastern nodes the same X-value, etc, pp.

---

Please note that "perfect square" strongly depends on the CRS you're using. A square created WGS 84 (EPSG 4326) wont be a square in the fitting UTM zone, and vice versa.